# I want to let user just enter a value in a table in sql just when that value in another table exists

Tags: sql

I have two tables. a and b. I want to deny user from entering values in a.column1 when the same value is not in the b.column1. how can I do this.
b.column1 is not unique.
for example
a.column1 has values as (22,23)
and 
b.column2 has values as (22,300, 23)

table a has a foreign key on two columns on table b, b.column1 & b.column2 .
These two column on table b are unique together, and I defined them as pk for table b. they are related to two columns on table a.
now if the user enters 22 or 23 or 300 it is ok but not any other values.
can you please help me
appreciated

Comment: Are the users writing their own insert statements?

Comment: no. they enter just through a TextBox. they have no Access to the databaxe

Comment: table b can have data as ( 22,23,23,23,22,300,300)

Comment: Create a stored procedure that excepts an INT as a parameter, Check to see if the value exists in Table B , if so do the insert If not return and error. What do you need help with, how far have you gotten?

Comment: Tag the DBMS you use in your question and I can edit my answer with syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Quite simple. This is where you need a FOREIGN KEY.

```
ALTER TABLE A
ADD FOREIGN_KEY(B_Col1)
REFERENCES B(column1);
```

Comment: I used the foreign key, (but it isnot on just one column, on column 1, and column2). I expected as you said, it works, but it doesnot work

Comment: Please edit the question to indicate this. Also, provide real examples.

Comment: I was to send the real example, but the if Statement given  above worked. thank you for your  Attention.
but I still have a question. isnt it right that fk should work here and prevent enetring data into the tabel when is not in the parent table or i am wrong

Comment: cool. I still have trouble understanding your question but upvote the correct answer.

Comment: I cannot upvote. unfortunately, i am new here. but I am still curious about understanding the meaning of fk. i think that I didnt understand it completely. I expected it prevent false data, but in practice it didnt maybe because of Composite columns in the table.

Comment: A foreign key ensures referential integrity - the column in the child table will have to bear a value defined in the column on the parent table. A composite foreign key shouldn't be a problem, but it is not clear what you're doing. We may be able to explain better if you run `desc` on the table and post the results as part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TableB WHERE Column1=23)
  INSERT INTO TableA  (column1) Values(23)
ELSE
select 'error'
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a CHECK CONSTRAINT in a.colum1. something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE
ADD CONSTRAINT chk_a_colum1 CHECK (a.column1 NOT IN (SELECT b.column1 FROM b));
```